# How do you know what system call is invoked when an executable file is run?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

If you open sublime-text in Linux Mint, which of **exec()** or **system()** gets called?

Comment: where's the research effort? what did you try so far?

Comment: `system()` is a libc function, not a system call.

Comment: +1 because google took me here for my question and the answer is what I wanted. But the question itself is very poor indeed. lol

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to track the system calls made a program:

```
$ strace -o mystrace.log sublime-text
```

That will output a chronological list of the system calls traced to the file `mystrace.log`. The first system call in the log will probably answer your question: typically, a variant of `exec*` is called such as [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).

If you're curious about how executable binary files actually run however, check out the [differences between raw binary and ELF files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427229/1806289).