# Format of Firmware images of Embedded devices

Tags: elf, firmware

Many resources state that Firmware image is an ELF file/format. I've checked that by executing `file command` using several firmware images `(.bin)`, the outcome of this command doesn't mention anything related to ELF. Unlike when I executed the same command over ELF files, where I was receiving something like `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Renesas SH, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`.
The reason I'm asking about that, I want to test an approach for detecting malicious ELF files, I already have the ELF malicious files, but I don't have benign ELF files, therefore was thinking if I can use Firmware images as benign ELF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Firmware will be in a binary format, referred to as a bin file.
So these bin files would not be useful for your test.
Here is an answer discussing the difference between the two formats.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427229/7275012